# Why does this enum parameter work for a single field and not for a collection?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jpql

Consider the following JPA Entity (implementation is Hibernate 4.3.0):

```
@Entity
public class MyEntity {

    @Id
    protected long myEntityId;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    public Condition myCondition = Condition.BAD;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @ElementCollection
    public Set<Condition> conditions = new HashSet<Condition>();

    public enum Condition {
        GOOD, FAIR, BAD, SOL
    }
}
```

When I run the following query with an enum parameter, I get 0 results (no error):

```
//Produces no results
String queryString = "FROM MyEntity me WHERE :condition MEMBER OF me.conditions";
List<MyEntity> things = JPA.em().createQuery(queryString, MyEntity.class).setParameter("condition", Condition.BAD).getResultList();
```

This query produces the following SQL:

```
select myentity0_.myentityid as myentity1_38_, myentity0_.mycondition as mycondit2_38_ 
from MyEntity myentity0_ 
where ? in (
    select conditions1_.conditions 
    from MyEntity_conditions conditions1_ 
    where myentity0_.myentityid=conditions1_.MyEntity_myEntityId)
```

If I use a string literal instead, I get results.  I also get results if I use the same parameter strategy for non-collection fields:

```
// Produces results
queryString = "FROM MyEntity me WHERE 'BAD' MEMBER OF me.conditions";
things = JPA.em().createQuery(queryString, MyEntity.class).getResultList();

// Also produces results
queryString = "FROM MyEntity me WHERE me.myCondition = :condition";
things = JPA.em().createQuery(queryString, MyEntity.class).setParameter("condition", Condition.BAD).getResultList();

//So does this
String queryString = "from MyEntity me join me.conditions c where c = :condition";
List<MyEntity> things = JPA.em().createQuery(queryString, MyEntity.class).setParameter("condition", Condition.BAD).getResultList();
```

These queries produce the following SQL:

```
select myentity0_.myentityid as myentity1_38_, myentity0_.mycondition as mycondit2_38_ 
from MyEntity myentity0_ 
where 'BAD' in (
    select conditions1_.conditions 
    from MyEntity_conditions conditions1_ 
    where myentity0_.myentityid=conditions1_.MyEntity_myEntityId)

select myentity0_.myentityid as myentity1_38_, myentity0_.mycondition as mycondit2_38_ 
from MyEntity myentity0_ 
where myentity0_.mycondition=?

select myentity0_.myentityid as myentity1_38_, myentity0_.mycondition as mycondit2_38_ 
from MyEntity myentity0_ 
    inner join MyEntity_conditions conditions1_ on myentity0_.myentityid=conditions1_.MyEntity_myEntityId 
where conditions1_.conditions=?
```

Am I wrong in my assumption that Hibernate should take care of `EnumType.STRING` and `EnumType.ORDINAL` when you use parameters?  At the least, it's inconsistent.  Filling in parameters works when querying enum fields but not enum collections.  What am I missing?

Comment: As well as the answer you have been given, you can always help yourself by actually debugging it ... looking at the SQL generated ... and looking at the JPA spec that says _Expressions that evaluate to embeddable types are not supported in collection member expressions_

Comment: @Neil Stockton  What makes you think I didn't try things for myself?  You have here in the question my attempt to isolate and identify the issue in a simplistic entity.  I suppose I could have mentioned that the SQL generated by the first and third JPQL queries is the same.  As for the JPA spec--do enum elements count as embeddables?  I was under the impression that embeddables were essentially subclasses annotated as embeddable.

Comment: People can only comment on what they have been presented with, and most people on here present little to no debugging, so that is always the assumption. As for your problem I can run that (well, once I add in SELECT {alias}" make it valid JPQL) in the JPA provider I use (DataNucleus) and it creates an SQL like `SELECT * FROM MYENTITY M INNER JOIN MYENTITY_CONDITIONS B0 ON M.ID = B0.MYENTITY_ID WHERE B0.CONDITIONS_ELEMENT = <'BAD'>`, so works fine. Consequently your JPA provider seems to be where the problem is, not your code

Comment: Interesting--when I write the JPQL to include a join, it produces SQL that includes an inner join like you show, but it uses `in` if I use `member of`.  Also, since the only difference between the SQL produced by the parameterized query and the literal query is the parameter itself, I think you're right that it's the way my provider (Hibernate) is handling the parameters. I was hoping I was just using it incorrectly.

Comment: I had the same issue and was not able to get to the bottom of it, but was able to rewrite my query to just inner join on the enum collection field where it matched my desired enum value and then count the results (>0 indicating that the collection did contain the desired enum value).

Answer (score 2):

You have a wrong mapping, so the results are unpredictable.

You missed the `@ElementCollection`, using only `@Enumerated` on a `Collection` it's not a valid mapping.

---

**update**

It seems the problem is somewhere else.

You should add the generated SQL, so we can have more info.

I've tried on an equivalent schema, and the query runs fine:

```
return em.createQuery("from DocumentType x where :family member of x.families", DocumentType.class)
    .setParameter("family", DocumentFamily.GENERIC)
    .setMaxResults(5)
    .getResultList();
```

and also

```
from DocumentType x where 'GENERIC' member of x.families
from DocumentType x join x.families f where f = :family
from DocumentType x join x.families f where f = 'GENERIC'
from DocumentType x join x.families f where f = it.shape.edea2.jpa.enums.DocumentFamily.GENERIC
```

there are two different generated SQL queries:

```
select ...
from ELEMENT_TYPE documentty0_ 
where documentty0_.DTYPE='DocumentType' 
    and ('GENERIC' in (
        select families1_.FAMILY 
        from DOCUMENT_TYPE_FAMILY families1_ 
        where documentty0_.ID=families1_.DOCUMENT_TYPE_ID)) 
limit 5

select ...
from ELEMENT_TYPE documentty0_ 
    inner join DOCUMENT_TYPE_FAMILY families1_ on documentty0_.ID=families1_.DOCUMENT_TYPE_ID 
where documentty0_.DTYPE='DocumentType' 
    and families1_.FAMILY='GENERIC' 
limit 5
```

but there's something strange:

```
from DocumentType x where it.shape.edea2.jpa.enums.DocumentFamily.GENERIC member of x.families
```

throws

```
org.hibernate.QueryException: Unrecognized Hibernate Type for handling query constant (it.shape.edea2.jpa.enums.DocumentFamily.GENERIC); expecting LiteralType implementation or AttributeConverter
```

wich version of Hibernate are you using?

I'm on 5.2.2

Comment: My mistake.  When making the example I left out that annotation.  The same behavior still occurs with the annotation. I'll update the question to reflect this.

Comment: Using 4.3.0, as stated in question.  Using a join like this on the collection works with the parameter, so it must be related to what @Neil Stockton was saying about collections.  Though I still don't know why an enum would be considered an Embeddable.

Comment: @Indigenuity It must be a bug in 4.3.0 which is pretty old (Dec-2013). You may try to run 4.3.11 and check if the bug has been resolved.

Comment: I get the same "Unrecognized Hibernate Type" exception with Hibernate 5.3.7 using the FQN of the enum. Using the String version works as well.